# How can I modify a nested object value in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to update the city value and call a post request. I can modify and update the name property but I can modify that city.

This is the JSON.

```
{
    "name": "something",
    "address": {
        "city": "something"
    }
}
```

My model

```
class TestModel {
  String? name;
  Address? address;

  TestModel({this.name, this.address});

  TestModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    address =
        json['address'] != null ? new Address.fromJson(json['address']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    if (this.address != null) {
      data['address'] = this.address!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Address {
  String? city;

  Address({this.city});

  Address.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    city = json['city'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['city'] = this.city;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I don't need the API calling code. I just want to modify and print the full model values. Thank you.
Main code:

```
  Future<void> submit() async {
    testModel.name = 'something';
    testModel.address?.city = 'London';
    print(testModel); //Expacted output: full model data like {"name": "something","address": {"city": "London"}
}
```

Expected output: full model data like

```
{"name": "something","address": {"city": "London"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change

```dart
Future<void> submit() async {
    testModel.name = 'something';
    testModel.address?.city = 'London';
    print(testModel); //Expacted output: full model data like {"name": "something","address": {"city": "London"}
}
```

to this:

```dart
Future<void> submit() async {
    testModel.name = 'something';
    if (testModel.address != null) {
        testModel.address.city = 'London';
    }

    // You can also force the address update using
    // testModel.address = Address(city: 'London');
    // but it's up to you and your logic
    
    print(jsonEncode(testModel));
}
```

`jsonEncode()` will call the method `toJson()` on your `testModel`, transforming it into a map. Further informations here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should make sure an Address exists before setting the city:

```
testModel.name = 'something';
testModel.address ??= Address();
testModel.address!.city = 'London';
```

If `testModel.address` is not set, `testModel.address?.city = 'London';` will have no effect.